# Is there an easy way to receive Http POST request in python, like in php?

Tags: python, php, http-post

I am implementing a simple Android app, that needs to send data to a webserver. I currently use a HttpUrlConnection to send the data via a POST request to a php script on the server.

```
$value1 = $_POST["value1"];
$value2 = $_POST["value2"];
```

The values are received like simplified shown above. In the app I use the url, where the script is saved on the server.

Is there a simple way to get this done with python too? Or are there just some more complex solutions?

I could only find multiple ways of sending request with python or exchanging data within the webserver. But nothing worked for my project.

Comment: https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/ ...just for example

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but I already found and implemented that one. Which didn´t work. But maybe I did somethink wrong. I just get the whole python code as return, when testing the code with the insomnia client. If I send a request to the script to "myserver/testScript.py", it just returns the whole python code.

Comment: you can't run it as PHP in Apache (which has special module to run PHP code) but you need server which can run Python code or you have to run server built-in in Flask. WIth Apache you would also use `cgi-module` which can run CGI code (any executable script - Python, Perl, Bash, etc.) and then you would need different module in Python - and code should be in folder `bin` or `cgi-bin`

Comment: you should run it as `python script.py` and it should start server built-in in `Flask`. And you have to connect to URLs which you have defined in `app.route(..)` - not to `myserver/testScript.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python the easier way to get `POST`  is to use `Flask` and run it with built-in server.

**script.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      value1 = request.form.get('value1')
      value2 = request.form.get('value2')
      return 'OK'
   else:
      return 'Use POST requests'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

and run as

```
python script.py
```

and it will run server on port `8000` so you can connect `http://myserver:8000/`

---

But if you already run `Apache`/`nginx` with `PHP` then this makes problem.

You can't run both servers on the same port `80`. It would need to run all with `Apache`.

`PHP` was created for web pages and `Apache` has preinstalled module to run `PHP` (and to run PHP frameworks like `Laravel`) but usually it doesn't have module for `Python`. It may install module to run Python or other module to run CGI or FastCGI (which means any executable script - Python, Perl, Bash, and even compiled C/C++) but this is very old method which needs different modules in Python - so rather it can't run `Flask` - and probably nobody use it. `Flask`, `Django`, `Bottle` is simpler to write code, has many built-in functions and code is cleaner and better organized - like in PHP frameworks.

`Flask` and other Python web frameworks (like `Django`, `Bottle`) are created to run with WSGI severs like `Gunicorn`. They use eventually `Apache` only as `proxy-server` and to serve static files like images, CSS. So to use Flask/Django on external server you would have to find server which is configured for `Flask`, `Django`, etc. like [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)

---

In `PHP` you can mix all in one file - code, HTML, SQL - so it can make big mess and people created frameworks like `Laravel` to make it cleaner and better organized. In `Python` you use at start framework so you would have to compare `Flask` with PHP frameworks but not with pure PHP.